# Python MySQL convert DateTime and Decimal values into Readable values

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a MySQL database with ~300 values. The data is being inserted through a Java app, but I can't change anything there. The values that I am getting are:

```
|id|user|datetime|weight|
```

In that order. When I get the values from the database using python I get this (an example row):

```
(1, 'User', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 19, 23, 48, 38), Decimal('159.8'))
```

I want to get the id, user and date(in yyyy-MM-dd format), and get the decimal, but I want the row to look like this:

```
(310, 'User', '2019-07-19', '159.8')
```

I have no idea what to do, or where to start. How can I get the values to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get from the database is a tuple. Members of a tuple can't be changed.

To get a tuple in the form you want, it would be necessary to create a new tuple with the changed items.

Note that it would be necessary to include the datetime and decimal modules.

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

new = []
i=(1, 'User', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 19, 23, 48, 38), Decimal('159.8'))
new.append((i[0], i[1], i[2].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), str(i[3])))

print(new)
```

This prints:

```
[(1, 'User', '2019-07-19', '159.8')]
```

I think this may solve the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

```py
date = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 19, 23, 48, 38)
datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

`'%Y-%m-%d'`` will get it into the yyyy-MM-dd format you desire.

You will need to import datetime first

Comment: Ok, but how would I extract the date from the row?

Comment: @RoXeno, if your tuple is `t = (310, 'User', '2019-07-19', '159.8')'` you can extract it with `t[2]`